# Checar se a URL dada é uma imagem

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou fazendo um aplicativo em Node.js, e quero fazer um sistema de planos de fundo customizados usando a URL dada pelo usuário, gostaria de saber como faço para verificar se a URL dada pelo usuário é uma imagem, e se não for, o aplicativo dá `return`.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o `file-type`:

```
npm install file-type
```

Código de exemplo:

```
const http = require('http');
const fileType = require('file-type');
const url = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png';

http.get(url, res => {
    res.once('data', chunk => {
        res.destroy();
        console.log(fileType(chunk));
    });
});
```

> Resultado:
>   { ext: 'png', mime: 'image/png' }

Um maneira de verificar se a `url` contém a imagem no formato que você quer:

```
if (!(fileType(chunk).ext == "png")) {
    console.log("deu ruim");
    // aqui vem o seu return
}
```

Exemplo tirado [daqui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type).

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido falar nesse package, mas como eu farei o sistema em que caso a URL não seja uma imagem o app dá `return`?

Comment: Você vai comparar o resultado do `fileType(chunk)` com os formatos que você quiser aceitar (png, jpg, etc.) ao invés de enviar pro console - se for `false`, você dá o seu `return` - o que acha?

Comment: @Gabriel Inclui no fim da resposta uma comparação com um tipo de extensão.

Comment: if (!(fileType(chunk).ext == "png")) {
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ext' of null

Comment: @Gabriel Tentou com a url que eu coloquei de exemplo?

Comment: sim, aí deu certo, depois mudei a URL pra ver se o código do return funcionava, e deu isso.

Comment: @Gabriel talvez seja interessante você abrir uma nova pergunta colocando o código e o erro que você está tendo - pq. acho que vai mudar demais essa pergunta aqui se você editar.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211351/erro-ao-usar-o-file-type