# Erro ao usar o file-type

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu tinha feito uma pergunta aqui ontem, e a Blogueira me ajudou, passando esse código:

```
const http = require('http');
const fileType = require('file-type');
const url = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png';

http.get(url, res => {
    res.once('data', chunk => {
      if (!(fileType(chunk).ext == "png")) {
    console.log("deu ruim");
    // aqui vem o seu return
}
        res.destroy();
        console.log(fileType(chunk));
    });
});
```

Mas, ao colocar uma URL em que não é uma imagem (e está em http) o erro a seguir é exibido:

```
      if (!(fileType(chunk).ext == "png")) {
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ext' of null
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Na pequena [documentação](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type), é indicado que se a URL não tiver uma imagem com formato compatível, ele retorna `null`:

> fileType(input)
>   Returns an Object with:
>   •ext - One of the supported file types
>   •mime - The MIME type
>   Or null when no match.

Então para resolver a sua questão, acredito que baste antes de fazer a comparação, verificar se o retorno é `null` - se for, a função termina ali:

```
http.get(url, res => {
    res.once('data', chunk => {
        if (!fileType(chunk)) return;
        // ... comparação, resto do código
    });
});
```

---

#### Edit:

Para apenas não gerar o erro caso a URL não aponte para uma imagem, é só testar primeiro se o retorno é `null`, e caso não seja, segue com a comparação:

```
const http = require('http');
const fileType = require('file-type');
const url = 'http://www.google.com';
// const url = 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png';

http.get(url, res => {
    res.once('data', chunk => {
        if (fileType(chunk)) {
            if (!(fileType(chunk).ext == "png")) {
                console.log("alguma outra imagem");
            } else {
                console.log("imagem em png!");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("url não contem imagem");
        }
        console.log("a função continua aqui, pois não demos return");
    });
});
```

Comment: Mas é geral, não? Eu só quero que não dê return quando não é um PNG.

Comment: @Gabriel Você pode usar o `if` só para impedir que ele dê erro - mas pode seguir com o programa ao invés de dar `return`.

Comment: @Gabriel Por favor veja minha edição na resposta (tentei deixar completa).